# Slice out a part of an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay, so I got this multidimensional array in my project with some different values in it. For example:

```
$myArray = array
    (
    array("Array1", 42, 57, 12, 27),
    array("Array2", 44, 59, 14, 29),
    array("Array3", 46, 1, 16, 31),
    array("Array4", 47, 2, 17, 32),
    array("Array5", 48, 3, 18, 33),
    array("Array6", 51, 6, 21, 36),
    array("Array7", 53, 8, 23, 38),
    array("Array8", 55, 10, 25, 40),
    array("Array9", 57, 12, 27, 42),
    array("Array10", 59, 14, 29, 44),
);
```

I want to extract only a part of myArray, and "disable" the other part of the array. So I only want this output:

```
$myArray = array
(
    array("Array1", 42, 57, 12, 27),
    array("Array2", 44, 59, 14, 29),
    array("Array3", 46, 1, 16, 31),
    array("Array4", 47, 2, 17, 32),
    array("Array5", 48, 3, 18, 33)
);
```

Is there any way of achieving this in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**array_slice()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) could help you.

```
$myArray= array_splice($myArray, 0, 5);

print '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
print '</pre>';
```